# React Native node_modules package errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, server

[image]While trying to run the server with the command 'node server', I'm getting an Error:

```
C:...path...\node_modules\react-native\index.js:13
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I tried to figure out the error, and got into that 'index', I saw a lot of errors like:

```
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
```

Error saying: ';' expected.

I did not mess with the node_modules package so I've no idea where did those errors came from.

Versions:

```
"react": "~16.11.0",


"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
```

Anyone who knows how to handle that problem ?

Comment: could you show version of React Native and React?

Comment: yes, just updated

Comment: react-native you have to run with `npm start` not `node server`. Read https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Yes, sure.
I built an app that communicate with the server.
'npm start' works well but the server is not.